# Get result from first thread completed

Tags: haskell

Say I want to compute two long running processes in two separate threads in Haskell.  However, I only care about the result from the first one done.  How would I do this?

Example (pseudo code):

```
thread1 = spark $ long_running some_arg1
thread2 = spark $ long_running some_arg2
result = first_done thread1 thread2 -- Maybe even first_done [thread1, thread2]?
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) package does this, and is now part of the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2012-November/104352.html).

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- async (threadDelay 2000000 >> return 1)
  y <- async (threadDelay 1000000 >> return 2)
  (_, res) <- waitAnyCancel [x, y]
  print (res :: Int)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the longer running thread killed you can use: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb

Otherwise you could do the same thing as unamb but leave out the killThread.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd work with `IO` threads, you could also use the latest [parallel-io](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-io-0.3.3) package, in particular [parallelFirst](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parallel-io/0.3.3/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-ParallelIO-Global.html#v%3aparallelFirst).